# How do you plot the fft of an audio signal in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have figured out how to get the audio sample to be read by Matlab. I have tried to use the documentation to plot the fft, but it is giving me a plot who's frequency spike is hard to read. Am i doing this correctly? Thanks for your help.

```
[y,Fs] = audioread('Grand Piano - Fazioli - minor chords - Dm lower.wav');
%sound(y,Fs); 
fftFs = Fs*2;

T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time
L= 2000;
t = (0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector
% Sum of a 50 Hz sinusoid and a 120 Hz sinusoid
plot(Fs*t(1:50),y(1:50))
title('Signal Corrupted with Zero-Mean Random Noise')
xlabel('time (milliseconds)')


NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y
Y = fft(y,NFFT)/L;
f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);

% Plot single-sided amplitude spectrum.
plot(f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1))) 
title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of y(t)')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('|Y(f)|')
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to see the tone better and not the entire series, you can use axis(0 0.1 0 1) for example

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There are a few problems with your code...You are completely overwriting the signal you're reading in...

Comment: Just noticed the scale is to 25 kHz.  Use something like axis (0 1e3 0 1)

Comment: I noticed I did that. I am trying to use the fft to plot the frequency spike of the input audio signal. The code has been corrected. I am not sure how to change the scale as stated by johnnymopo

Comment: Read the docs for `fftshift`. You can zoom in using the "magnifying glass" icon in the figure windows, no need to use `axis`. You can find the specific frequency at a peak using the "cursor" tool.

Comment: @MBaz oh, yes, that is simpler.   At least I didn't suggest a chirp transform....

Answer (score 1):

Try this; after your

plot(f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1)))

command. Insert the following command

axis([0,1,0,0.03]);

See the resultant plot.  Next, change that axis() command to

axis([0,0.5,0,0.03]);

See the resultant plot.  Then in your Matlab control window type

help axis

to learn how to use Matlab's axis() command.

Here's nitpick, "if I may be so bold." (Quote borrowed from Mr. Grady in the movie The Shining.) Your y-axis label is correct but your plot title should be changed from "Amplitude" to "Magnitude". It makes a difference. In signal processing amplitude values can be positive or negative. Magnitude values are *always* positive and Matlab's abs() command always produces magnitude values. (In some special situations it's possible to produce spectral amplitude plots, that contain spectral phase information, but that's not what you are plotting.)